# why setting drop_first=True doesn't always work in pandas.get_dummies for regresssion problem?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I have read a post: https://towardsdatascience.com/beware-of-the-dummy-variable-trap-in-pandas-727e8e6b8bde?gi=d742c1d0dd69 which says that `pandas.get_dummies` will case multicollinearity issue in regression problems.

> One of the assumptions of a regression model is that the observations must be independent of each other.

> ...

> If we look closely, Gender_Female and Gender_Male columns are multi-collinear. This is because a value of 1 in one column automatically implies 0 in the other. This issue is termed a dummy variable trap and can be represented as :

> `Gender_Female = 1 - Gender_Male`

The author said we can use `drop_first=True` in `get_dummies()` to solve this problem. However, I found it does not always work in reality.

I try to apply regression model to predict house prices for kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

I try to use some features of the dataset as follows:

```
numeric_columns = ["MSSubClass", "OverallQual", "OverallCond", "MoSold", "BsmtHalfBath", "BsmtFullBath", "GrLivArea",
                   "LowQualFinSF", "2ndFlrSF", "1stFlrSF"]

category_columns = ["Neighborhood"]
```

I use following code to process category_columns:

```
# here I compare the result for the parameter of drop_first
category_dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(df[category_columns], drop_first=True)
df = df.merge(category_dummy_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.drop(category_columns, axis=1)
```

The result is confusing to me. If I use `Neighborhood` feature as the category feature and setting `drop_first=True` will get worse rmse result. While if I use `MSZoning` feature as the category feature, then `drop_first=True` will get better result.

My question is that why setting `drop_first=True` doesn't always work in pandas.get_dummies for regresssion problem? It seems that different features will get different result. Then which kind of features will get a better result if we setting `drop_first=True`?

Comment: drop_first drops the first category. How many categories are there in Neightborhood?

Comment: @BorutFlis MSZoning feature contains 8 different categories and Neighborhood  feature contains 25 different catetories.

Comment: In that case drop_first won't do anything about the multicollinearity problem.

Comment: @BorutFlis Why？If one feature only contains 2 categories, then drop_first=True will work? Is this right?

Comment: I am not the biggest expert in using categorical variables in linear regression, but the example with gender has two variable male/female, hence what you get returned is just one binary column. With 8 features you will still get 7 columns after drop_first.

Comment: Perhaps you can add just one category dummy in the model.

Comment: @BorutFlis Thx, I just feel confused by the result. According the example of the post, male and female will be multi-collinear after get_dummies, so drop one column will work. For multi categories which is greater than 2, remaining columns will still be multi-collinear, thus drop_first will not work. But I am not sure I have the right idea

Comment: Yes. What you can do is use only one categorical dummy in the model.

Comment: @BorutFlis I found I am wrong. For feature categories that is greater than 2, remove one will solve the multi-collinear problem indeed. However, the performance of regression model does not improve. So the reason that  setting drop_first=True doesn't always work in pandas.get_dummies for regresssion problem is still unknown!

Comment: How do you measure performance? It is possible you get lower MSE with multi-colinearity in the data, but the probabilities are less reliable in terms of effects of individual independent variables.

Comment: I put all features into the model and only change the parameter drop_first. According to the analysis, if setting drop_first=True, then the features do not have multi-colinearity. Then not. I found the result is not always better by setting to be True.